# sql running totals

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, over-clause

i have a table with a list of items and qty to be sold by a certain due date.
I am trying to calculate a running total column that would show how many items would have been sold at a certain. below is my attempt to get the running totals but it doesn't work as I expect.

```
select item, due_date, qty, sum(qty) over (Order by item )
from apsplan 
Where item ='19-3102875'
order by item
```

I get the error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 44 Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

ps I am using SQL Server 2012.

Here is the alternative suggestion I received from here

```
SELECT
    item,
    due_date,
    qty,
    (SELECT SUM(t2.qty) FROM apsplan t2 WHERE t2.item <= t1.item and item = '196-31020-005') AS rolling_qty
FROM apsplan t1
WHERE
    item = '196-31020-005'
ORDER BY
    item
```

here is the result - not the running total but the over

```
item    due_date    qty rolling_qty
196-31020-005   2017-09-20 00:59:00.000 1.00000000  24.00000000
196-31020-005   2017-10-06 01:00:00.000 1.00000000  24.00000000
196-31020-005   2017-11-06 01:00:00.000 1.00000000  24.00000000
196-31020-005   2017-12-06 01:00:00.000 1.00000000  24.00000000
196-31020-005   2019-01-28 01:00:00.000 1.00000000  24.00000000
196-31020-005   2019-02-04 01:00:00.000 1.00000000  24.00000000
196-31020-005   2019-03-25 01:00:00.000 1.00000000  24.00000000
196-31020-005   2019-03-25 01:00:00.000 1.00000000  24.00000000
196-31020-005   2019-04-01 01:00:00.000 1.00000000  24.00000000
196-31020-005   2019-04-08 01:00:00.000 1.00000000  24.00000000
196-31020-005   2019-04-29 01:00:00.000 1.00000000  24.00000000
196-31020-005   2019-05-06 01:00:00.000 1.00000000  24.00000000
196-31020-005   2019-05-13 01:00:00.000 1.00000000  24.00000000
196-31020-005   2019-05-27 01:00:00.000 1.00000000  24.00000000
196-31020-005   2019-06-03 01:00:00.000 1.00000000  24.00000000
196-31020-005   2019-06-10 01:00:00.000 1.00000000  24.00000000
196-31020-005   2019-07-01 01:00:00.000 1.00000000  24.00000000
196-31020-005   2019-07-08 01:00:00.000 1.00000000  24.00000000
196-31020-005   2019-07-15 01:00:00.000 1.00000000  24.00000000
196-31020-005   2019-07-29 01:00:00.000 1.00000000  24.00000000
196-31020-005   2019-08-05 01:00:00.000 1.00000000  24.00000000
196-31020-005   2019-08-12 01:00:00.000 1.00000000  24.00000000
196-31020-005   2019-08-26 01:00:00.000 1.00000000  24.00000000
196-31020-005   2019-09-02 01:00:00.000 1.00000000  24.00000000
```

Comment: The query in the question looks fine. I don't see any syntax errors. Are you showing the actual query that you are trying to run, or some cut-down version?

Comment: I agree with Vladimir, executes fine. Since it states Line 44, I suspect this is part of a larger query and the problem lies elsewhere

Comment: @SEarle1986 that is the code as it is. The only thing I have above this is variations of the same query which I was playing around with before I came to this.....I have commented out all these such that the only lines the will run are the one I posted on here

Comment: @user2355773 are you sure the error is related to this code? It's reporting Line 44 and your code has  less rows. The second strange thing it reports Incorrect syntax near **'order'**. Note, it's lowercase, but your Order in **over (Order by item )** is Upperecase. I tryed to provoke similar error and the word Order was reported uppercase if I write it uppercase, so maybe it's NOT a row you are thinking about?

Comment: @user2355773 And please, update your question with the result of SELECT @@version

Comment: @sepupic I have updated the question and added the results I get. as you can see the rolling_qty field is not the running total but the overall total.

Comment: @user2355773 Sorry, but I still don't see the result of SELECT @@version

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Even though you are using SQL Server 2012, the actual functionality depends on the compatibility level.  You can query for the compatibility level using:

```
SELECT name, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases
```

This should be at least 110 for you to use the `order by` with `sum()`.  To change the compatibility, refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level).  If you have an older compatibility (perhaps less than 100 is needed), then you can get this error.

Comment: Actually, this is not true. At least, for SQL Server 2014 Express. `SUM(...) OVER (ORDER BY ...)` worked with compatibility level 100 of the user database in my test.